# GRUB booting wrong partition

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, ssd, grub

I have a dual-boot installation with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. I recently bought an SSD NVMe m2, and I would like to move the partition with Windows 10 on the SSD. In order to do this, I cloned the partition with Macrium Reflect on the SSD. Everything went ok. I updated GRUB with the command `update-grub` and the copy of the Windows 10 installation appeared on the GRUB menu located at the right place (on the ssd).

When I boot my computer up, GRUB shows both Windows 10 installations, one located on the HDD on /sda2, and the other one on the SSD. The problem is when I launch the installation on the SSD, I end being on the HDD Windows installation. Also, if I try to boot the SSD directly from the Boot Manager, it redirects me to the classic GRUB menu.